# combinatorics and cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the card game bridge, the $52$ cards are dealt equally to players 1,2,3 and 4. Given the fact that players 1 and 2 have $8$ spades, what is the probability that player 3 has $3$ spades? (Problem taken from *A First Course in Probability*, by Ross)

Proof try:

We assume the cards are withouth order. so  we have $\binom{5}{3}*\binom{21}{10}$ ways to choose $3$ spades out of $5$ and the other $10$ cards out of $21$, while the number of all possibilties is$ \binom{26}{13}$.
By division, we get the correct result.
On the other hand, if I assume the cards to be ordered, I do not get the same result.
We can choose the $3$ spades in $5*4*3$ ways. 
Then we can choose the other cards in the hand of player 3 in $21*20*...*12$. 
We must also multiply by $13*12*11$, as the $3$ spades can be anywhere in the hand Then divide by $26*...*14$, the number of all possibilities, and obtain a $3!$ bigger result.

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly 3, or at least 3?

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the three places where you want to put spades is (13*12*11)/(3*2*1)

Comment: To expound on Djura's answer, since you assumed that the cards were ordered, you had a first spade, a second spade, and a third spade, which would appear in that order, say from left to right. So you need only pick three places for your spades, and then automatically the first goes in the first place, and so on. That means there are $13 \choose 3$ ways to pick their positions, which is also $\frac{13!}{10!3!}=\frac{13*12*11}{3*2*1}$.

Comment: That's right, you are choosing already ordered places, you can't reorder them

Answer (score 0):

It is the **probability** that has been asked for.

Although not the way cards are actually distributed , we can  distribute them suitwise w/o affecting the results, so we simplify the problem by considering only spades, and only players $3$ and $4$

We have to distribute distribute a total of $5$ spades to players $3$ and $4$, each having $13$ slots, so that player $3$ gets three, and player $4$ gets two.

$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{26}{5}}$

---

**Added**

By the way, since probability is a ratio, whether we use permutations or combinations won't matter here, but we need to be consistent. We'll get the same answer by

$Pr = \dfrac{_{13}P_3\times_{13}P_2}{_{26}P_5}$